# FolderBrowserDIalog doesn't show network drives in Win 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

I have an application, that uses a folderBrowserDialog. 
In Windows XP it works fine, but in Win 2012 dialog doesn't show Network Drives.
I've tried to find a solution, but failed.
Maybe somebody has had the same issue.
Any help would be appreciated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this link (I know it mentions Windows 8...but 2012 shares the same kernel):

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8

You could try setting this registry option (could be broken in Win8):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System
    EnableLinkedConnections=1
```

Also see this for an explanation of why from Vista onwards with UAC turned on you may see different drive mappings:

- https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A2=WINDOWS-UK;833e5b39.1302

Comment: Especially following Link is interesting: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767400/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8#tabs

Comment: Updating this registry setting fixed the issue for me