# C# Folder browse Dialog not showing Network shared folders win10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have created an application(windows) compiled with .NET 4.6.1 and used the FolderBrowserDialog object. When a button is pressed I execute this code:

FolderBrowserDialog folderbrowserdialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

```
    folderbrowserdialog.Description = "Custom Description";

 if (folderbrowserdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
        filePath = folderbrowserdialog.SelectedPath ;

 }
```

what i get from the folderbrowserdialog(like foto)

[image]

however ,the folder browserdialog is not showing the networks shared folder(that the purpose of my app) otherewise just the pc folders.

but what i want to get it is the network shared folders which could i also access from windows 10 like foto here:

[image]

notes to be marked:
i could not use the open file dialog cause i need the folder location.
i desgined the Appto be opened just like admin by adding manisfest so the app is always starting like admin.
the app should be comptiable with windows 10,7
note i know that i could try setting this registry option (could be broken in Win10):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System
    EnableLinkedConnections=1
```

but it does not make a sense to add this registry by every customer PC

so is there any tipps to show the  network shared folders in FolderBrowserDialog ?

Comment: Mapped drives are user specific, so when the app runs as admin (a different user) it can't see the mapped network drives.

Comment: @Equalsk
the admin user is the same user who logged in :)
do u have any suggestion to let user(admin) see it ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251983/folderbrowserdialog-doesnt-show-network-drives-in-win-2012

Comment: @Equalsk i have just read this articel but it does not make a sense for me to add regedit key to every customer :( 
thanks any way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after reading many topics i found that the only solution is to add a Registry key programmatically so here how to add specfic C# Registry Subkey with dword value:

i wrote a method wich could all use it 
just to let you know after using it you have to restart the device after it ,it will work ;)

```
public void ConfigureWindowsRegistry()
{
    RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64); //here you specify where exactly you want your entry

    var reg = localMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System", true);
    if (reg == null)
    {
        reg = localMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System", true);
    }

    if (reg.GetValue("EnableLinkedConnections") == null)
    {
        reg.SetValue("EnableLinkedConnections", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Your configuration is now created,you have to restart your device to let app work perfektly");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The reason of the problem: I was using as an Administrator. The mapped drives are related to the user, so I tried to use as an normal user and I could see the mapped drives.